# XCode 4.3 import a nested header error: no such file or directory

Tags: iphone, import, header, nested, xcode4.3

I'm running into a nasty issue trying to import a header from a project that is embedded in my main project. What is the proper way to import `RKJSONParserJSONKit.h` indicated below?

I'm trying :
    #import "RestKit/Support/RKJSONParserJSONKit.h"

but Xcode cannot find that file.

[image: Project structure]

[image: folder structure]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up just copying the required files over from the sample project over to the main project. A very hasty choice, but spending hours debugging header search paths is not my favorite thing to do in Xcode :/

Answer (score 0):

Just do **`#import "RKJSONParserJSONKit.h"`**, no need to include **/ResKit/Support/**

Answer (score 0):

you have to import the JSONKit

```
#import <RestKit/JSONKit.h>
```

if you have a problem with importing it as above try to load the kit by

```
#import "RestKit/Code/Support/Parsers/JSON/RKJSONParserJSONKit.h"
```

but you should add a copy of the **RKParser.h** into your project